# Next.js 13 App Routing Internationalization Issue: Locale Not Maintained Across Page Navigation

Tags: next.js

I'm having a problem with internationalization in a Next.js 13 application using app routing. I followed the official Next.js guide on internationalization ([Next.js Internationalization Guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization)). While most features work correctly, I'm facing an issue with maintaining the selected locale during page navigation.

**Issue Description:**

- Language switching using `localeSwitcher` functions correctly.
- However, when navigating to a different page using `router.push(..)` or `<Link href='/some/link'>`, the new page loads in the default locale instead of the currently selected one.
- It appears that the locale is not being automatically appended to the URL in the new App routing system, a feature that was present in the older pages routing approach as described here: [Link Component - Locale](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/link#locale).

**Attempted Workaround:**

- As a temporary fix, I'm considering a utility function to prepend the locale to URLs before passing them to the Link component.

**Question:**

- Is there an official or more integrated solution in Next.js 13 for this issue, which I might be overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those facing the same issue: Next.js has removed built-in internationalized routing with the release of the App Router: "*With the release of the App Router, internationalized routing has been removed as a built-in Next.js feature*". I couldnt' find this info in the Next.js docs, but I found it in a third-party library they reference, [next-i18n-router](https://github.com/i18nexus/next-i18n-router). Using this library fixed the issue for me.